# Add jquery date picker in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display jquery date picker in angularjs,but am getting error as `element.datepicker is not a function`.

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div>
            <label>Date<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="levFrom" datepicker ng-model="leave.from_date"  required>
        </div>
</form>
<script>
    var app = angular
                    .module("myApp", [])
                    .directive("datepicker", function () {

                        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                            element.datepicker({
                                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                            });
                        }
                        return {
                            require: 'ngModel',
                            link: link
                        };
                    })
                    .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
                    })
</script>
```

whats wrong in my code?

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/n0sb4CVoSqb0TfRblOLX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this one directive
app.directive("datepicker", function () {
return {
restrict: "A",
require: "ngModel",
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
  var updateModel = function (dateText) {
    scope.$apply(function () {
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
    });
  };
  var options = {
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
      updateModel(dateText);
    }
  };
    elem.datepicker(options);
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: app is not model..app will hold your application

Comment: can you please provide a Plunker or fiddle ?